# WinAPI SetupDiGetClassDevs seg faults in wxWidgets app unless called from static method

Tags: c++, winapi, wxwidgets

This static class method works perfectly

```
class cHID
{
public:
    static void TestStatic();
};

void cHID::TestStatic()
{
    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (DeviceInfoSet)
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    }
}

cHID::TestStatic();
//cHID theHID;
//theHid.Test2();
```

However, the identical code in a non-static method segment faults inside SetupDiGetClassDevs()

```
class cHID
{
public:
    void Test2();
};

void cHID::Test2()
{
    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (DeviceInfoSet)
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    }
}

//cHID::TestStatic();
cHID theHID;
theHid.Test2();
```

I would much prefer calling SetupDiGetClassDevs from a non static method, so I can save some results in class attributes.

This is a wxWidgets "hello world" program. I copy it to a console program and both methods to work. So wxWidgets isn't playing nicely with SetupDiGetClassDevs?

Here is the complete failing wxWidgets program

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/app.h>
#include <wx/textdlg.h>

#include <setupapi.h>
#include <ddk/hidsdi.h>

class cHID
{
public:

    void Test1();
    static void TestStatic();
};


class cApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    virtual bool OnInit();

};

class cFrame: public wxFrame
{
public:
    cHID theHID;

    cFrame(wxFrame *frame, const wxString& title)
        : wxFrame(frame, -1, title, wxPoint(-1,-1),wxSize(600,600))
    {
    //    cHID::TestStatic();
            cHID theHID;
            theHID.Test1();

    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(cApp);

bool cApp::OnInit()
{
    cFrame* frame = new cFrame(0L, "HIDGraph");
    frame->Show();

    return true;
}

void cHID::Test1()
{
    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (DeviceInfoSet)
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    }
}
void cHID::TestStatic()
{
    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (DeviceInfoSet)
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    }
}
```

Here is the complete passing console program

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ddk/hidsdi.h>
#include <setupapi.h>

using namespace std;

class cHID
{
public:
    static void TestStatic();
    void Test2();
};

void cHID::TestStatic()
{
    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (DeviceInfoSet)
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    }
}

void cHID::Test2()
{
    GUID HID_GUID;
    HidD_GetHidGuid( & HID_GUID );
    HDEVINFO DeviceInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevs(
                                 &HID_GUID,
                                 NULL,NULL,
                                 DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);
    if (DeviceInfoSet)
    {
        SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(DeviceInfoSet);
    }
}

int main()
{
//cHID::TestStatic();
    cHID theHID;
    theHID.Test2();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Maybe you have some kind of stack corruption just before your call to `Test2` ?

Comment: Method calls and static calls don't work the same way. The fact is : the code you posted works for me. This obviously means that the problem is in the code you didn't post. My first guess is that something gets corrupted, so maybe you have a buffer overflow or a misplaced `free`/`delete`. It will probably be hard to tell without more information ,maybe some code or details about the seg fault. Also, are you using Visual Studio ? VS is often really good at debugging these kind of things.

Comment: My test program does nothing else.  However, it is a wxWidgets "hello world" program.  I copy this to a console program and both methods work.  So wxWidgets isn't playing nicely with SetupDiGetClassDevs?

Comment: I don't think calling `SetupDiGetClassDevs` is the problem, maybe there is something wrong with your wxWidgets program. You should post the whole program if it isn't too long.

Comment: Whole programs posted

Comment: There is no *segmentation fault* in Windows. What error are you really experiencing? Don't make up error codes or error messages.

Comment: @ravenspoint So, I tried you example with wxWidgets, and it also works, no seg fault. How did you link the libraries (`setupapi`)? I don't see any `#pragma comment(lib,"setupapi")`, are you sure you linked the correct version ? Also, your include `<ddk/hidsdi.h>` is suspicious; the ddk folder is for driver development, and probably not what you want. The correct include is just `<hidsdi.h>`.

Comment: I ran the program again ( to provide linspectable with details of the error ) and now it works fine.  Sheesh!  Thanks @ElderBug for your trouble and attention.